# Should this list initializer behavior be reported as bug in the Visual Studio C# Compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, list, compilation, initialization

First of all I will say that I've changed my design and no longer need that but getting a good answer for that will still be nice

I have the following `class`, `ListContainer`, in my code *(The attached codes are all [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))*:

```
class ListContainer
{
    public object ContainedList
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public ListContainer(object list, int value)
    {
        ContainedList = list;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And in some other `class` in my code I have a `List<ListContainer>` and I need each `ListContainer` to contain this `List<ListContainer>`, so I can implement it like that:

```
//Field in the class
List<ListContainer> mContainers = null;

//In the constructor:
mContainers = new List<ListContainer>();
mContainers.Add(new ListContainer(mContainers, SOME_CONST));
mContainers.Add(new ListContainer(mContainers, SOME_OTHER_CONST));
```

Than it works fine, but when I've tried to use ***list initializer***:

```
//Field in the class
List<ListContainer> mContainers = null;

//In the constructor:
mContainers = new List<ListContainer>
{
    new ListContainer(mContainers, SOME_CONST),
    new ListContainer(mContainers, SOME_OTHER_CONST)
}
```

You would expect the results to be equivalent but in reality the result looks like that:

```
mContainers
    [0] - ListContainer
              ContainedList = null
              Value = SOME_CONST
    [1] - ListContainer
              ContainedList = null
              Value = SOME_OTHER_CONST
```

Seeing this results I've inspected the output MSIL of this C# compilation and seen the following code:

[image: MSIL lists]

Now, this explains why the problem occurs, and I've even checked out in the ***CSharp Language Specification*** document and this is the defined behavior:

> A List can be created and initialized as follows:
>
> ```
> var contacts = new List<Contact> {
>     new Contact {
>         Name = "Chris Smith",
>         PhoneNumbers = { "206-555-0101", "425-882-8080" }
>     },
>     new Contact {
>         Name = "Bob Harris",
>         PhoneNumbers = { "650-555-0199" }
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> which has the same effect as
>
> ```
> var __clist = new List<Contact>();
> Contact __c1 = new Contact();
> __c1.Name = "Chris Smith";
> __c1.PhoneNumbers.Add("206-555-0101");
> __c1.PhoneNumbers.Add("425-882-8080");
> __clist.Add(__c1);
> Contact __c2 = new Contact();
> __c2.Name = "Bob Harris";
> __c2.PhoneNumbers.Add("650-555-0199");
> __clist.Add(__c2);
> var contacts = __clist;
> ```
>
> where __clist, __c1 and __c2 are temporary variables that are otherwise invisible and inaccessible.

So obviously this behaviour is intended. Is there a good reason everything is done on the temporary variable and not on the original one? since it seems like a wrong behaviour to me.

Comment: For those who voted for "Primarily opinion based" note that I'm asking if there are reasons that this behaviour is good, this is not an opinion based question.

Comment: Since it took me forever to realize what the actual difference is, here a note for whoever is equally confused: The initializer for `mContainers` is referencing itself but at that time, the reference is still `null`.

Comment: There is no temporary list. There is a temporary variable. The variable *is not* an object, though. Its a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is to avoid race conditions with concurrent threads accessing the original variable where you would add your elements. An inconsistency would appear if a thread accesses the variable while not all elements are added to it yet.

Two threads accessing the same variable would therefore get an inconsistent list, with different elements in it.

This would not come as a shock if the elements are added on different lines, but since you use an object initializer, it is normal to perceive the object as directly initialized with all its elements in it, hence the need of a temporary, invisible, variable.

Comment: What still annoys me with it is that the list initializer only exists as a sweet syntax for the normal initialization and `Add`s so it should have behaved the same...

Comment: well, yes and no. It's syntactic sugar, yes, but philosophically, it's a different concept: _ObjectInitializer_ : your object is _Initialized_ with those values _already_ set. If you can access your object before the initialization is complete, then it can't be called an object _initializer_

Comment: This is not race condition protection. ECMA allows the JIT to undo this transformation entirely. If this is your only protected against races you have none.

Comment: I am very interested in your comment, @usr: could you please elaborate?

Comment: When you say a=1;b=2; the stores are not guaranteed to happen in that order. ECMA guarantees almost nothing when it comes to ordering of unsynchronized operations. It's a common mistake to assume that the operations happen in the same order as the source language (C#) defines them. Here in particular the list contents are not guaranteed to be visible even though they happen before publishing the list.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good reason everything is done on the temporary List and not on the original one?

There is no original list:

```
var __clist = new List<Contact>();
// …
__clist.Add(__c1);
// …
__clist.Add(__c2);
var contacts = __clist;
```

Only one list is ever created. What you probably mean is that it’s done on a temporary variable instead of the original variable, but that has no practical effect—other than probably being easier to implement. This is especially true if you think about that collection initialization is not limited to the context of variable assignments:

```
SomeMethodCall(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Since there is no reference to that list, the simplest solution to implement this is just to use a temporary variable that holds the list, and put that variable at the place of the initializer then.

What’s also important about this is that the old value is completely overwritten. So in your `mContainers = new List<ListContainer>`, the old value of `mContainers` is never being looked at for the purpose of the initializer syntax.

It’s probably a good idea to think about the collection initialization as an “atomic” operation. The list only exists (at least to you) once the whole initializer completes. So you cannot reference itself from within the initializer.

Comment: +1 for the "atomic operation", it is a little bit weird since list initialization is really not an atomic operation in its nature but I get the point of making it practically atomic.

Comment: @FabioSalvalai That’s just the same list though; there is only one list object.

Comment: it's not a temporary variable, really, you're right. it's some kind of "decompression chamber" where  a  "temporary version of the object, which shall not be used" is being built before it is finally exposed as an object that can be leveraged. (sorry, I removed my previous comment to write this one ;))

Comment: But nobody can modify it from another thread since the variable is not assigned yet. (during the `Add` ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

Assignments are first evaluated on the right side of the `=` and then the assignment takes place. So `mContainers` is still null.

Comment: Reread my question, I understand what's going on I just don't understand what did behavior is good for.